# updating gradle wrapper files gives different results

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

`gradle version` --> 2.11

in an empty directory i start new gradle project asking for wrapper 2.14.1:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-distribution-url https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

then i commit everything:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m'gradle wrapper'
```

now i update wrapper to the same version but using wrapper for this:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-distribution-url https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

and it seems that all files have changed: `git status`:

```
    modified:   gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
    modified:   gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
    modified:   gradlew
    modified:   gradlew.bat
```

why i got different jar and wrapper scripts? i ask for the same version of wrapper using different gradle distribution and i get completely different result. why? and what is the correct way of updating wrapper jar AND wrapper scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like the `./gradlew wrapper ...` command imports the wrapper files (jar and scripts) from the version you requested. the `gradle wrapper` command imports the wrapper for the same version as your local gradle installation